# CSS / UI: Button pops up onmouseup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I am trying to make an HTML button scale / pop up when the user releases the button after pressing it.

So currently, on mouse down (:active) I scale my button down to .95. It pops back up to normal (scale=1.0) when it is released, but I actually want to go up to scale=1.1 then back down to normal to give the user the impression that the button pops up when released.

However, the only way I can think of doing this is with JQuery (onmouseup.) I would prefer to use CSS.

How can I use CSS selectors to make the button pop up on mouse release?

Comment: Read up on @keyframes CSS animations, that's exactly what you want.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've tried using keyframes but I wasn't able to attach the animation to a mouseup event in the CSS.

Comment: Attach the start animation to foo:active and the end animation to plain foo.